# Como hacer que la columna de un dataGridView de tipo checkBox sea la primera y que la cabecera también sea un checkBox (seleccionar todos)

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

Buenos días tengo un `DataGridView` al que le asigno como `DataSource` un `DataTable` con el resultado de una consulta.

```
public static void FiltreGridArticles(string familia,string subfamilia, DataGridView grid)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string lcSql = "SELECT codigo,nombre FROM " + DB.SQLDatabase("GESTION", "articulo");
    string filtre = "";
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subfamilia))
    {
        filtre = $" WHERE familia={familia} AND subfamilia = {subfamilia}"; 
    }
    else 
    {
        filtre = $" WHERE familia ={familia}";
    }
    lcSql += filtre;
    DB.SQLExec(lcSql, ref dt);
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    AddCheckColumn(grid);
}
```

La última instrucción añade una columna del tipo CheckBoxColumn:

```
public static void AddCheckColumn(DataGridView dgv)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    chkCol.Name = "colCheck";
    dgv.Columns.Add(chkCol);
}
```

No tengo muy claro si lo estoy realizando de la mejor forma, el caso es que me gustaría que esta fuera la primera columna y no la última y como puedo hacer que la cabecera de esta columna sea también un checkBox para seleccionar/desseleccionar todos los registros.
Gracias!

**EDIT**: He logrado desplazar la columna a la primera posición, tan simple como `chkCol.DisplayIndex=0` perdonad.
Lo que no logro es que el header de la columna sea un checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está el código de como lo hago por si a alguien le interesa:
[Cómo acceder a propiedades de un control creado de forma dinamica en una clase estàtica desde otro formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373957/c%c3%b3mo-acceder-a-propiedades-de-un-control-creado-de-forma-dinamica-en-una-clase-e)