# Cómo acceder a propiedades de un control creado de forma dinamica en una clase estàtica desde otro formulario

Tags: c#, datagrid, delegados

necesitaba crear una columna de `CheckBox` en un `DataGridView` y en la cabecera de esta un `CheckBox`de seleccionar todos.
Lo hice en forma de métodos en una clase estática a los que le paso el `DataGridView` y me lo montan.
Los metodos en cuestion son:

```
//Añade la columna de checkboxs en la primera posicion.
public static void AddCheckColumn(DataGridView dgv)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    chkCol.Name = "colCheck";
    chkCol.HeaderText = "";
    chkCol.Width = 30;
    chkCol.ReadOnly = false;
    dgv.Columns.Insert(0,chkCol);
}
//Crea un objeto CheckBox, lo asocia a la colección de controles del DataGridView y lo mueve al lugar del header.
public static void CheckHeader(DataGridView dgv, EventHandler HeaderCheck_Clicked)
{
    CheckBox chkHead = new CheckBox();
    Point headerCellLocation = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
    int cellWidth = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1,true).Width;
    int cellHeight = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Height;
    chkHead.Location = new Point(headerCellLocation.X + 8, headerCellLocation.Y + 2);
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.White;
    chkHead.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    chkHead.Size = new Size(18, 18);
    chkHead.Click += HeaderCheck_Clicked;
    dgv.Controls.Add(chkHead);
}
```

El problema lo tengo en el evento `click` del `CheckBox` del `header`, que como veis, se lo paso al método como parámetro a través de un delegado para poder llamarlo desde el formulario principal:

```
    private void frmOfertes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
        string queryCmbFam = "SELECT codigo,nombre from " + DB.SQLDatabase("GESTION", "familias");
        cmbSubfam.Enabled = false;
        funcions.EmplenaCombo(queryCmbFam, cmbFam);
        funcions.AddCheckColumn(ewgrid1);
        funcions.FiltreGridArticles(cmbFam, cmbSubfam, ewgrid1);
        funcions.CheckHeader(ewgrid1, HeaderCheck_Clicked);
        Dictionary<string, int> ampleCamps = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"codigo",80 },
            {"nombre",200 }
        };
        funcions.ColumnSize(ampleCamps, ewgrid1); 
    }

    private  void HeaderCheck_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ewgrid1.EndEdit();
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkbox = (row.Cells["colCheck"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell);
            chkbox.Value = chkHead.Checked;
        }
    }
```

Lo que hago en este evento, es igualar los `CheckBox` de la columna del `DataGridView` al estado del `CheckBox` del `header` y aquí viene el problema, no sé cómo hacerlo, ya que este `checkbox` lo creo dinámicamente en el método `CheckHeader()` de la clase estática, a alguien se le ocurre como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Pero el evento que asocias al checkbox del header se ejecuta en el form con lo cual tienes acceso al grid para iterar las rows y acceder a la columna de checks

Comment: Con la colección `Controls` del DataGrid?

Comment: A las rows y a la columna de checks no tengo ningún problema en acceder, el problema está en la última línea: `chkbox.Value = chkHead.Checked;` para establecer el mismo estado en los checks de las rows que el que tiene chkHead, ya que a este no se como acceder.

Comment: Por favor, no edites tu pregunta para hacer una nueva pregunta.. en su lugar, hace una pregunta nueva, si no la respuesta queda invalida....

Comment: Ok, lo siento, borro edición.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar el `sender` para acceder al `checkbox` del header que lanza el evento

```
private  void HeaderCheck_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chkHead = (CheckBox)sender;

    foreach(var row in ewgrid1.Rows)
    {
        var chkbox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["colCheck"];
        chkbox.Value = chkHead.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: No había caído en eso.Muy amable.

Comment: Perdona Leandro por el incordio, pero me ha surgido otro problema con ese `checkbox`.
Si selecciono todos los registros mediante el check de seleccionar todos, quiero hacer que al quitar uno de la selección se demarque el check del header, pero una vez más, no sé cómo acceder a este check, ya que ahora no dispongo del sender para ello como en tu respuesta anterior.:
Edito mi pregunta para adjuntar código.

Answer (score -1):

```
private CheckBox chkHead;

public static void CheckHeader(DataGridView dgv, EventHandler HeaderCheck_Clicked)
{
    chkHead = new CheckBox();
    Point headerCellLocation = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
    int cellWidth = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1,true).Width;
    int cellHeight = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Height;
    chkHead.Location = new Point(headerCellLocation.X + 8, headerCellLocation.Y + 2);
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.White;
    chkHead.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    chkHead.Size = new Size(18, 18);
    chkHead.Click += HeaderCheck_Clicked;
    dgv.Controls.Add(chkHead);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor, explica por qué funciona tu código.